# SonarQube OpenEdge custom rule to verify &IF preprocessor with Proparse

Tags: sonarqube, openedge

I am trying to create a custom plugin, based on the [Riverside OpenEdge plugin](https://github.com/Riverside-Software/sonar-openedge) and its version of **Proparse** to create a rule that valids a &IF preprocessor.

This rule needs to verify if the application is using a deprecated value of a `&GLOBAL-DEFINE` like this:

```
/* "A" is the deprecated value of "opts" so I want to create a new ISSUE here */
&IF "{&opts}" = "A" &THEN
    MESSAGE "DEPRECATED CODE".
&ENDIF

&IF "{&opts}" > "A" &THEN
    MESSAGE "OK CODE".
&ENDIF
```

For this rule I extended I tried to do something like this:

```java
if (unit.getMacroGraph().macroEventList.stream().noneMatch(macro -> macro instanceof NamedMacroRef
        && ((NamedMacroRef) macro).getMacroDef().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("opts"))) {
    return;
}

TokenSource stream = unit.lex();
ProToken tok = (ProToken) stream.nextToken();

while (tok.getNodeType() != ABLNodeType.EOF_ANTLR4) {
    if (tok.getNodeType() == ABLNodeType.AMPIF) {
        // Verify node.
        System.out.println(tok);
    }

    tok = (ProToken) stream.nextToken();
}
```

But I don't know if its the best way to verify (I did based on the code from other sources) and it's not working because the next node comes as an empty "QSSTRING". I am very new in the **Proparse** world, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to know that Proparse doesn't give access to every detail of the preprocessor. That said, the method `unit.getMacroGraph()` will give you access to the visible part of the preprocessor, so that's a good starting point.
If you're looking for usage of given preprocessor variable, you can search for NamedMacroRef instances pointing to the right MacroDef object (with `NamedMacroRef#getMacroDef()#getName()`), and the right value.

In a old-style for-each loop:

```
for (MacroRef ref : unit.getMacroSourceArray()) {
  if ((ref instanceof NamedMacroRef)) {
    if ("opts".equalsIgnoreCase(((NamedMacroRef) ref).getMacroDef().getName())
        && "A".equalsIgnoreCase(((NamedMacroRef) ref).getMacroDef().getValue())) {
      System.out.println("OPTS variable usage with value 'A' at file " + ref.getFileIndex() + ":" + ref.getLine());
    }
  }
}
```

On this file:

```
&global-define opts a
&IF "{&opts}" = "A" &THEN
    MESSAGE "DEPRECATED CODE".
&ENDIF
&undefine opts
&global-define opts b
&IF "{&opts}" > "A" &THEN
    MESSAGE "OK CODE".
&ENDIF
```

This gives:

```
OPTS variable usage with value 'A' at file 0:2
```

So you don't have access to the expression engine, but I think that the current API is enough for what you want to do.

You can then report the issue with SonarQube with `OpenEdgeProparseCheck#reportIssue()`

Comment: Hi @gilles-querret, thank you for your reply. The situation here is that I need to validate the comparison value `= "A "` not the value of the variable itself. The variable is in an include with the value "B", so the source code compiled with that include contains only the value "B" for the `opts` variable.

Comment: Preprocessor expressions are not exposed in the AST, and preprocessor tokens are discarded after consumption by the next layer of TokenStream (i.e. you can't access them through getHiddenTokensBefore as you could do with whitespaces). So for now, you'd have to use the lex() method (as in your code sample), and look for `ABLNodeType.AMPIF`. You can have a look the code in [PostLexer](https://github.com/Riverside-Software/sonar-openedge/blob/master/proparse/src/main/java/org/prorefactor/proparse/antlr4/PostLexer.java).

Comment: If you like living on the bleeding edge, you can try the branch [feature/PreprocessorExpression](https://github.com/Riverside-Software/sonar-openedge/tree/feature/PreprocessorExpression) in which the &IF expressions are available as hidden tokens (like whitespaces)